# GeneralLink field breaks in CE when using ampersand (&) in description

Tags: content-editor, experience-editor

*Using sitecore 8.1 update -1*

When adding a description that includes & (e.g. hola & hello) to a GeneralLink field, the error below is thrown and the value is not shown on either content editor or content tree. The issue is that CE is not translating `&` to `&amp;` -confirmed by checking raw values.

However, if I add the value using content tree, it saves `&amp;` but doesn't show using normal view and will break again if any changes are made using content tree. I heard this was fixed in 8.2 but can't find the fix.

Error:

> 13684 10:45:48 ERROR First 200 characters: 
>   13684 10:45:48 ERROR Call stack:    at Sitecore.MainUtil.GetCallStack()
>      at Sitecore.Xml.XmlUtil.LoadXml(String xml)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Link.SetValue()
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.EditorFormatter.RenderField(Control parent, Field field, Item fieldType, Boolean readOnly, String value)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.EditorFormatter.RenderField(Control parent, Field field, Item fieldType, Boolean readOnly)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderInput(Field field)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderElement(XmlNode element)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderChildElements(XmlNode element)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderMarker(XmlNode element)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderElement(XmlNode element)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderChildElements(XmlNode element)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderSectionPanel(XmlNode element)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderElement(XmlNode element)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.AddText(XmlNode element)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderElement(XmlNode element)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.AddText(XmlNode element)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderElement(XmlNode element)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.Render(XmlDocument skin)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.Process(RenderContentEditorArgs args)
>      at (Object , Object[] )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor.Render(RenderContentEditorArgs args, Control parent)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.RenderEditor(Item item, Item root, Control parent, Boolean showEditor)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.UpdateEditor(Item folder, Item root, Boolean showEditor)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.Update()
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnPreRendered(EventArgs e)
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
>      at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those who can't upgrade to 8.2, sitecore support has provided a solution. I'll post the code here as I don't know a better way of sharing the library.

*As a reference*
Ticket number: 471609 | Sitecore Support - Bug #109428

Code provided contains 2 classes and a javascript change.

1. `LinkRenderer.cs` overrides default `RenderFieldResult` method
2. `GetLinkFieldValue.cs` calls method in LinkRenderer.cs
3. `\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\ExperienceEditor.js` amends method `postServerRequest` to encode string.

### LinkRenderer.cs

```cs
public class LinkRenderer : Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.LinkRenderer
{
    private readonly char[] _delimiter;

    public LinkRenderer(Item item) : base(item)
    {
        this._delimiter = new char[]
        {
            '=',
            '&'
        };
    }

    public override RenderFieldResult Render()
    {
        SafeDictionary<string> safeDictionary = new SafeDictionary<string>();
        safeDictionary.AddRange(base.Parameters);
        if (MainUtil.GetBool(safeDictionary["endlink"], false))
        {
            return RenderFieldResult.EndLink;
        }
        Set<string> set = Set<string>.Create(new string[]
        {
            "field",
            "select",
            "text",
            "haschildren",
            "before",
            "after",
            "enclosingtag",
            "fieldname",
            "disable-web-editing"
        });
        LinkField linkField = base.LinkField;
        if (linkField != null)
        {
            safeDictionary["title"] = HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(StringUtil.GetString(new string[]
            {
                safeDictionary["title"],
                linkField.Title
            }));
            safeDictionary["target"] = StringUtil.GetString(new string[]
            {
                safeDictionary["target"],
                linkField.Target
            });
            safeDictionary["class"] = StringUtil.GetString(new string[]
            {
                safeDictionary["class"],
                linkField.Class
            });
        }
        string text = string.Empty;
        string rawParameters = base.RawParameters;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawParameters) && rawParameters.IndexOfAny(this._delimiter) < 0)
        {
            text = rawParameters;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            Item targetItem = base.TargetItem;
            string text2 = (targetItem != null) ? targetItem.DisplayName : string.Empty;
            string text3 = (linkField != null) ? linkField.Text : string.Empty;
            text = HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(StringUtil.GetString(new string[]
            {
                text,
                safeDictionary["text"],
                text3,
                text2
            }));
        }
        string url = this.GetUrl(linkField);
        string linkType;
        if ((linkType = base.LinkType) != null && linkType == "javascript")
        {
            safeDictionary["href"] = "#";
            safeDictionary["onclick"] = StringUtil.GetString(new string[]
            {
                safeDictionary["onclick"],
                url
            });
        }
        else
        {
            safeDictionary["href"] = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(StringUtil.GetString(new string[]
            {
                safeDictionary["href"],
                url
            }));
        }
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("<a", 47);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> current in safeDictionary)
        {
            string key = current.Key;
            string value = current.Value;
            if (!set.Contains(key.ToLowerInvariant()))
            {
                FieldRendererBase.AddAttribute(stringBuilder, key, value);
            }
        }
        stringBuilder.Append('>');
        if (!MainUtil.GetBool(safeDictionary["haschildren"], false))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                return RenderFieldResult.Empty;
            }
            stringBuilder.Append(text);
        }
        return new RenderFieldResult
        {
            FirstPart = stringBuilder.ToString(),
            LastPart = "</a>"
        };
    }
}
```

### GetLinkFieldValue.cs

```cs
public class GetLinkFieldValue : Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetLinkFieldValue
{
    protected override Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.LinkRenderer CreateRenderer(Item item)
    {
        return new Sitecore.Support.Xml.Xsl.LinkRenderer(item);
    }
}
```

### sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\ExperienceEditor.js

```js
postServerRequest: function (requestType, commandContext, handler, async) {
  var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/" + requestType,
    data: {
      __RequestVerificationToken: token,
      /*Sitecore Support - Bug #109428*/
      data: jQuery("<div/>").text(decodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(commandContext))).html()
    },
    success: handler,
    type: "POST",
    async: async != undefined ? async : false
  });
}
```

### Config patch

```xml
<sitecore>    
  <pipelines>
    <renderField>
      <processor type="Sitecore.Support.Pipelines.RenderField.GetLinkFieldValue, Sitecore.Support.109420" patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetLinkFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
    </renderField>
  </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

Answer (score 13):

This is a known bug. I've seen it fixed in the 8.2 release notes.

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes - reference 82835.

Unfortunately, I've not seen any workarounds for your release. I suggest you get in touch with Sitecore support.

Eventually, I assume, the above fix will be rolled into an 8.1 update release.